# Función de frecuencia usando NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Dispongo de una lista del tipo:

```
lista=[[('Yo','PRP'),('como','VB'),('patatas','NNP')],
       [('Tú','PRP'),('comes','VB'),('y','CONJ'),('yo','PRP'),('bebo','VB')]]
```

Estoy intentando obtener como output otra lista que contenga la frecuencia de cada tipo de palabra. He escrito la siguiente función, pero logro solo obtener las freciencias del primer elemento (primera frase) de la lista.

```
import nltk

def complexity_sentences(corpus):
    for comment in corpus:
        tag_fd = nltk.FreqDist(tag for (word, tag) in comment)
        return tag_fd.most_common()
print (complexity_sentences(list))
```

Salida (como se ve, el análisis corresponde solo al primer elemento):

```
[('PRP', 1), ('VB', 1), ('NNP', 1)]
```

¿Cómo obtengo las frecuencias de todas las frases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
for comment in corpus:
    tag_fd = ...
    return tag_fd.most_common()
```

La función retorna en la primera iteración del `for`. Por otro lado, en cada iteración reescribes la variable `tag_fd`. Debes hacer algo así:

```
import nltk

lista=[[('Yo','PRP'),('como','VB'),('patatas','NNP')],
       [('Tú','PRP'),('comes','VB'),('y','CONJ'),('yo','PRP'),('bebo','VB')]]

def complexity_sentences(corpus):
    tag_fd = nltk.FreqDist(tag for comment in corpus for (word, tag) in comment )
    return tag_fd.most_common()
print (complexity_sentences(lista))
```

Con lo que obtienes:

> [('PRP', 3), ('VB', 3), ('NNP', 1), ('CONJ', 1)]

Si por un casual quisieras hacer el recuento individualmente por cada comentario entonces basta con:

```
def complexity_sentences(corpus):
    return [nltk.FreqDist(tag for (word, tag) in comment).most_common() 
                                  for comment in corpus]
```

> [[('PRP', 1), ('VB', 1), ('NNP', 1)],
>     [('PRP', 2), ('VB', 2), ('CONJ', 1)]]